# Porting iPhone UI with multiple screens over a map to Android. Use multiple Activities?

Tags: iphone, android, android-layout

I have this setup in an iPhone app:

There is always a MKMapView on screen & a additional UI layer on top. The upper UI layer is managed by a simple state system. Each state is a UIViewController and has a .nib attached to it containing the layout.

I'm very new to Android development. What is the best way to build this on Android?

So far I see two options:
1. Have a single Activity & insert/remove layouts as the states change.
2. Have multiple Activities and have a layout for each. Is there then a way to keep a single MapView around beneath, without having one per activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, it is easier to have multiple activities, each with their own layout.

Before you get to far, make sure you read through the basic [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) and [UI guidelines](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html).  Android has some UI paradigms that are a little bit different from the iPhone, so you generally don't want to just copy over exactly what you have.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks. Could you add a little info on how you would go about keeping a single MapView beneath the layouts for each activity?